# PHP/JS: Profilephoto resize and cutting

Tags: php, javascript

Hi i just went on a site, when you press "upload image" a lightbox comes up, and then it says upload image, you browse find a image and then you press submit. After that, it shows your image with a square that you can move around and make bigger smaller /width/height.. so you like cutting. After that you can save, and you now have a new avatar.

What have they done for doing that? 
Is there any library or so to do this? Would like to have that on my webpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They used something called jCrop in jQuery.
http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`PHP GD library`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) [`imagecopy`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php) on how to **[crop images via PHP](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread185667.html)**.

Answer (score 0):

They are likely using a Jquery + the GDLibrary or Imagick Library for PHP.

Comment: Using jQuery **AJAX** to call **PHP** files